# C++ not detecting string in cases

Tags: c++

C++ beginner here. I've tried a ton of ways to try and fix this code but I think the way to correct it is far beyond what I know.

```
switch (num)
{
case 0: enemy == "Ogre";
    enetotal = "250";
    enehealth = "250";
    eneattack = "5";
    break;
case 1: enemy == "Goblin";
    enetotal = "75";
    enehealth = "75";
    eneattack = "10";
    break;
case 2: enemy == "Orc";
    enetotal = "100";
    enehealth = "100";
    eneattack = "25";
    break;
case 3: enemy == "Dark Elf";
    enetotal = "70";
    enehealth = "70";
    eneattack = "15";
    break;
case 4: enemy == "Lizardman";
    enetotal = "200";
    enehealth = "200";
    eneattack = "20";
    break;
}


cout << "You walk past a field when you see a " + enemy +", what do you do? \n";
```

Basically, what is supposed to happen is that, depending on a random case, it would choose a name and the health/attack for a certain enemy. It was working fine when I just had the enemy name, but once I added the attack and health it simply printed

```
You walk past a field when you see a, what do you do?
```

Something tells me cases can't handle that many lines, but I've tried many other things such as if statements and nothing seems to work. Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Also, have someone show you how to step through with a debugger.  That's a huge part of learning to program, and would have shown you where the error was right away

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing the name

```
enemy == "Orc"
```

Instead of assigning

```
enemy = "Orc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong: `==` is a test `=` is assignment.